# Are there monsters with both Magic Resistance and Legendary Resistance?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

Such monsters would be really hard enemies for casters. 
I could not find any in the Monster Manual below CR21, do these exist in newer books?

Comment: Any reason you excluded Antimagic Cone (see the Beholder) from this question? It can be extremely potent against spellcasters.

Comment: it is targeted, with good strategic positioning you can avoid it

Comment: And what about Limited Magic Immunity?

Comment: By below do you mean CR21 or less or CR20 or less

Comment: @DavidCoffron below CR21 _means_ CR20 or less

Comment: Fixed. I just wanted to make sure that's what you meant

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Yes, there are quite a few.

### Monster Manual (MM)

- Adult Blue Dracolich (CR 17)

### Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes (MToF)

- Archdevil Bael (CR 19)
- Sibriex (CR 18)
- Archdevil Titivulus (CR 16)

### Princes of the Apocalypse

> - Ogremoch (CR 20)
>  - Olhydra (CR 18)
>  - Imix (CR 19)
>  - Yan-C-Bin (CR 18)

### Volo's Guide to Monsters (VGtM)

- Elder Brain (CR 14)
- Ki-Rin (CR 12)

---

### The Ones Above CR 20

- The rest of the Archdevils (MToF)
- Each Demon Lord (MToF)
- Molydeus (MToF)
- Empyrean (MM)
- Tarrasque (MM)
- Illithilich (VGtM)
- **[Spoilers for Rise of Tiamat]**

  > If you include Limited Magic Immunity you can add Tiamat to the list